# How to remove a video from the currently playing playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

There used to be a "Remove from playlist" link to remove any video from the currently playing playlist, as in this screenshot:

[image]

However this link seems to be gone now. Is there any other way to remove a video from a playlist?

I'm on Firefox/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

It still exists but apparently not for all playlists. Only one didn't have it from what I could find.

A proof
[image: screen shot]

Link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09R8_2nJtjg&list=RD09R8_2nJtjg